# Unity2d Trying to make camera follow after destroying gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get my camera to follow my character after it is being destroyed/respawned. Is there any way to make this happen? I've attached the three scripts I have here(each script has it's separate file);

```
//Camera Following Script//
using UnityEngine;

public class FollowCam : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform target;
    public Vector3 offset;
    [Range(1,10)]
    public float smoothFactor;

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Follow();

    }

    void Follow()
    {
        Vector3 targetPosition = target.position + offset;
        Vector3 smoothPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, targetPosition,smoothFactor*Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        transform.position = targetPosition;
       
    }
}
```

```
//Level Manager//
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LevelManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static LevelManager instance;
    
    public Transform respawnPoint;
    public GameObject playerPrefab; 


    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    public void Respawn()
    {
        Instantiate(playerPrefab, respawnPoint.position, Quaternion.identity);
    }

  
}
```

```
//Player Death and Resapwn//
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerDeath : MonoBehaviour
{
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Spike"))
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            LevelManager.instance.Respawn();
        }

        if (collision.gameObject.CompareTag("Death"))
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
            LevelManager.instance.Respawn();
        }
    }
}
```

Also this is the error I'm getting. I know what it's asking I just don't know how to fix it.

```
MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'Transform' has been destroyed but you are still trying to access it.
Your script should either check if it is null or you should not destroy the object.
UnityEngine.Transform.get_position () (at <e414e10bfe5f45729ff122f3359de21b>:0)
FollowCam.Follow () (at Assets/Scripts/FollowCam.cs:18)
FollowCam.FixedUpdate () (at Assets/Scripts/FollowCam.cs:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of destroying your character just move character layer to a layer that invisible to camera. This way when character prefab will seem like destroyed but you will be able to access it without instantiating all you need to do just change layer back. If you want to change something like lose item/gold set it in the same part of code.

Comment: it's a fantastic idea to just change layers, to hide something. AAA